# How to disable spring-cloud config server for dev properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I integrate spring cloud in my spring app. It works fine. But I have 3 properties files :
**application.properties**

```
server.port 9101

spring.profiles.active=@env@
logging.level.org.springframework.data=debug
logging.level.=error
```

**application-dev.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

#TRACE DEBUG or INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=INFO
spring.application.name=microservice-payment
spring.cloud.config.enabled = false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gara-mpayment
spring.datasource.username=garauser
spring.datasource.password=garauser
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
server.servlet.session.timeout=10s


#RabbitMq configuration
rabbitmq.queueName=mpayment.queue
rabbitmq.exchangeName=mpayment-exchange
rabbitmq.routingKey=mpayment.routingkey
```

**and applictaion-int.properties**

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=my-url
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=username
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=pwd
```

I could I disable spring cloud for dev profile in order to use the local content of application-dev.properties and activate only for applictaion-int.properties ?

I tried `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=false` without success.

Comment: Do you mean how can you disable Spring Cloud Config Server?
If so, where did you add `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false`?

Comment: @MarcosBarbero sorry for the wrong title. I modified it. When I add `spring.cloud.config.enable=false` in my application-dev.properties I have this error : 
`Invalid config server configuration.

Action:

If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration.  If you are using a native profile and have spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration`

Comment: If I am not mistaken you need to add these properties to the `bootstrap.properties` as the config-server is needed during the bootstrap phase.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero already added but without success. I found that I should use `spring.profiles.active=native`, but with this I can't access my applictaion-dev property for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the solution here : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1503#event-2910814394

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(EnvironmentRepository.class)
@Profile("dev") // profile name
class NativeRepositoryConfiguration {
@Bean
public NativeEnvironmentRepository nativeEnvironmentRepository(NativeEnvironmentRepositoryFactory factory,
        NativeEnvironmentProperties environmentProperties) {
        return factory.build(environmentProperties);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should make a  bootstrap.yml or properties file and add `spring.cloud.config.enable=false`

or set a environment variable and disable the spring cloud

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html

Refer the above link for the error you mentioned `Invalid config server configuration. Action: If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration. If you are using a native profile and have spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration`

Comment: according to documentation I should add `spring.profiles.active=native` to my properties file. So in my application-properties, when I add the `spring.profiles.active=native`, Spring tells me that no profile is set, so i can't use the dev property for example.

Comment: Try adding vm argument in the run configuration:

`-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`